# How can I stream an image to YouTube using FFmpeg?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

I have an image that changes every few seconds. How can I stream it to YouTube using FFmpeg?

Comment: please add a link to the youtube API you are trying to use.

Comment: I can stream video over RTMP. Don't need an API for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -loop 1 -i input.jpg -re -f lavfi -i anullsrc -vf format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -b:v 2000k -maxrate 2000k -bufsize 4000k -g 50 -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://output
```

- `-f image2` is needed to manually select the [image demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#image2-1). Otherwise, depending on the input format, it may choose a different demuxer that does not allow arbitrary replacing of `input.jpg`.
- Replace `input.jpg` atomically (such as with `mv` but not `cp`) or else it may fail.
- YouTube requires audio. The [anullsrc](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#anullsrc) filter will generate silent audio.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: YouTube Streaming](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/EncodingForStreamingSites).
- (Optional) Use the slowest `-preset` that provides 25 fps (or whatever frame rate you set using the `-framerate` image demuxer input option).