# Youtube stream of looping JPG stops randomly

Tags: ffmpeg

Hi I'm fairly new at ffmpeg.

I'm currently trying to get a low FPS Youtube stream working over RTMP using a JPG on loop which content gets changed using a NodeJS script periodically. I'm using the following command to stream (variable 3 is my stream key):

```
ffmpeg -re -loop 1 -pix_fmt bgr24 -framerate 5 -i img/now.jpg -re -stream_loop -1 -i output.mp3 -f flv -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -g 60 -keyint_min 30 -b:v 400k -minrate 400k -maxrate 400k -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -bufsize 2000k rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$3
```

There's multiple things wrong here. The bitrate doesn't actually stay at 400k/s. It just goes to around 200-1000k and then just starts decreasing until the stream stops (usually at around 200-300k bitrate). It still seems like data is being sent (bitrate and current FPS are still updated (though they're very low) and speed goes parabolic. The frame counter itself just stops and Youtube doesn't continue streaming. See example:

```
frame=  515 fps=5.0 q=12.0 size=    5803kB time=00:01:42.84 bitrate= 462.3kbits/
frame=  518 fps=5.0 q=11.0 size=    5824kB time=00:01:43.41 bitrate= 461.3kbits/
frame=  519 fps=5.0 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:43.92 bitrate= 460.2kbits/
frame=  519 fps=5.0 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:44.42 bitrate= 457.9kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.9 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:44.92 bitrate= 455.8kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.9 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:45.43 bitrate= 453.6kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.9 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:45.93 bitrate= 451.4kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.9 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:46.44 bitrate= 449.3kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.8 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:46.94 bitrate= 447.2kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.8 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:47.44 bitrate= 445.1kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.8 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:47.95 bitrate= 443.0kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.8 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:48.45 bitrate= 440.9kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.8 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:48.96 bitrate= 438.9kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.7 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:49.46 bitrate= 436.9kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.7 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:49.96 bitrate= 434.9kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.7 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:50.44 bitrate= 433.0kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.7 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:50.95 bitrate= 431.0kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.7 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:51.45 bitrate= 429.1kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.6 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:51.96 bitrate= 427.1kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.6 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:52.46 bitrate= 425.2kbits/
frame=  519 fps=4.6 q=11.0 size=    5838kB time=00:01:52.99 bitrate= 423.2kbits/
```

I'm using a Digital Ocean VPS to run it, but the same happens on my own desktop which definitely has the hardware for a simple stream like this. Could it have something to do with me replacing the JPG content while trying to stream it? I get this error every once in a while, but it seems like it fixes itself judging by the info:

```
[mjpeg @ 0x562824d1fb40] overread 8
[mjpeg @ 0x562824d1fb40] EOI missing, emulating
```

I can provide more information if it's needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you only have problems when replacing the image?

Comment: @llogan Okay I feel stupid for not having tried this. It works fine while the image isn't being replaced. Any idea to remedy this or am I SOL?

Comment: Try `ffmpeg -re -f image2 -loop 1 -framerate 5 -i img/now.jpg -re -stream_loop -1 -i output.mp3 -f flv -vcodec libx264 -vf format=yuv420p -profile:v main -g 60 -keyint_min 30 -b:v 400k -minrate 400k -maxrate 400k -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -bufsize 2000k -c:a aac rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/$3`, and ensure that you replace `now.jpg` atomically (such as by using `mv`).

Comment: @llogan gonna test this out, might be a couple hours to see if it's actually stable (seems to be for now). Got any resources on why adding image2 would fix something like this?

Edit:
If this doesn't work, my next attempt will be to just pipe the image data to ffmpeg every time it's available and use image2pipe.

Comment: You ususally don't need to set `-f image2`. I'm assuming your command is defaulting to the muxer jpeg_pipe which does not appear to allow arbitrary input image replacement (but I did not really look into it much), so image2 is used instead which does. Basically a duplicate of [How can I stream an image to YouTube using FFmpeg?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67369016/)

Comment: This is embarrassing. I used that question as reference and misread the part about replacing the files atomically. I thought I actually **shouldn't** use mv or cp. Anyway thanks for putting up with this.